# Qt QML ListView sections visible when out of range

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I am having trouble bounding my ListView in QML.

I have taken the example provided by Qt (slightly modified but the exact code from the Qt example has the same issue), and tried to integrate it into my window.

As you can see in the image below, the ListView is supposed to be the size on the white Rectangle in the middle, yet the section headers are always visible, and the list elements are visible until completely out of the container Rectangle ("Guinea Pig" and "Tiger" are completely visible, although one would expect them to be only half visible)

[image: ListView bounding error]

I am sure the error is trivial, but i have tried all sorts of anchors and container types, but can't resolve this issue.

Here is the code :

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    id: myWindowId
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    visible: true
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 600
    height: 980
    color: "#333333"

    Rectangle {
        id: container
        x: 150
        y: 400
        width: 300
        height: 360

        ListModel {
            id: animalsModel
            ListElement { name: "Ant"; size: "Tiny" }
            ListElement { name: "Flea"; size: "Tiny" }
            ListElement { name: "Parrot"; size: "Small" }
            ListElement { name: "Guinea pig"; size: "Small" }
            ListElement { name: "Rat"; size: "Small" }
            ListElement { name: "Butterfly"; size: "Small" }
            ListElement { name: "Dog"; size: "Medium" }
            ListElement { name: "Cat"; size: "Medium" }
            ListElement { name: "Pony"; size: "Medium" }
            ListElement { name: "Koala"; size: "Medium" }
            ListElement { name: "Horse"; size: "Large" }
            ListElement { name: "Tiger"; size: "Large" }
            ListElement { name: "Giraffe"; size: "Large" }
            ListElement { name: "Elephant"; size: "Huge" }
            ListElement { name: "Whale"; size: "Huge" }
        }

        // The delegate for each section header
        Component {
            id: sectionHeading
            Rectangle {
                width: container.width
                height: childrenRect.height
                color: "lightsteelblue"

                Text {
                    text: section
                    font.bold: true
                    font.pixelSize: 20
                }
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: view
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            width: parent.width
            model: animalsModel
            delegate: Text { text: name; font.pixelSize: 18; color: "red" }

            section.property: "name"
            section.criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
            section.delegate: sectionHeading
        }
    }
}
```

Please could someone tell me the correct way to display this ListView ?

Comment: Did you try setting `clip: true`?

Comment: Damn, i knew it would be trivial, but i completely missed that one. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing the `clip` property. That tells the object to prevent child objects from drawing outside of its borders. `clip` is set to false by default because most of the time its not needed and has a little bit of a performance hit.

```
ListView {
    clip: true
    ...
}
```